# Combine two lists while adding common values

Tags: python

I have two lists of sets I'd like to combine, while adding the second set value when the first value matches.

Example input:

```
listOne = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 5)]
listTwo = [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 4)]
```

Desired output:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 4), ('c', 6), ('d', 5)]
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to write code, which you do not appear to have attempted to do.

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import Counter
result = list((Counter(dict(listOne)) + Counter(dict(listTwo))).items())
```

Comment: thanks everybody for the cleanup edits

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting the following error: "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required" is this because my lists are different lengths?